# Python multithreading Manager.list(), how to access data correctly

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm building a class that starts up in its own process and pushes data to my database in batch sizes.  This class uses a `Manager.list()` to get data.  I figured this would be a common pattern, database access in a separate process, but I couldn't find an appropriate library so I thought I would roll my own.

I'm using `threading.Timer` internally to wake up my database worker and inspect the shared queue.  However, when it wakes up there is nothing in the queue (despite content being put there).  Am I using the `Manager.list()` incorrectly?

Source code:

```
import random
from threading import Timer
import threading

from sqlalchemy import *
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from util.config import get_connection


def __convert_to_key(connection, table):
    return "{}.{}".format(connection.name, table.name)


class ConnectionWorker():
    __batch_size = 1000
    __batch_insert_queue = None
    __manager = Manager()
    __wait_interval = 5.0
    __finish = False
    __connection = None
    __table = None
    __timer = None
    finished = False

    def __init__(self, connection, table):
        self.__lock = threading.RLock()
        self.__connection = connection
        self.__table = table
        p = Process(target=self.__insert_data)
        p.start()

    def get_batch_insert_queue(self):
        self.__lock.acquire()
        try:
            if self.__batch_insert_queue is None:
                self.__batch_insert_queue = self.__manager.list()
            return self.__batch_insert_queue
        finally:
            self.__lock.release()

    def __insert_data(self):
        print("__insert_data, the queue is {}".format(len(self.get_batch_insert_queue())))
        q = self.get_batch_insert_queue()

        #push everything now if we have been told to finish
        if self.__finish:
            print("__finish flag has been set")
            self.__connection.execute(self.__table.insert().values(q))
            self.finished = True
            return

        #if there is nothing to do then just sleep
        if len(q) == 0:
            print("The queue is empty, sleeping")
            self.__timer = Timer(self.__wait_interval, self.__insert_data)
            self.__timer.start()
            self.__timer.join()

        values_to_insert = []
        while len(q) > 0 and len(values_to_insert) < self.__batch_size:
            values_to_insert.append(q.pop)
        print("Inserting {} values".format(len(values_to_insert)))
        self.__connection.execute(self.__table.insert().values(values_to_insert))

        #don't sleep if the queue has more work to do
        if len(q) >= self.__batch_size:
            print("Not sleeping, there is more work to be done, {} items".format(len(q)))
            self.__insert_data()
        else:
            print("Sleeping")
            self.__timer = Timer(self.__wait_interval, self.__insert_data).start()
            self.__timer.start()
            self.__timer.join()

    def finish(self):
        print("Setting finish to true")
        self.__finish = True

#test data
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #create the db and get metadata
    conn = get_connection()
    query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_test"
    try:
        conn.execute(query)
    except:
        pass
    query = """CREATE TABLE tmp_test (
    value bigint DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;"""
    conn.execute(query)

    metadata = MetaData()
    metadata.reflect(bind=conn)
    tbl = metadata.tables["tmp_test"]

    c = ConnectionWorker(conn, tbl)
    q = c.get_batch_insert_queue()
    for item in random.sample(xrange(1, 1000000000), 100000):
        q.append(item)
    print("The queue is {}".format(len(q)))
    print("The batch queue is {}".format(len(c.get_batch_insert_queue())))
    import time
    time.sleep(10)
    c.finish()

    while not c.finished:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Run log:

```
__insert_data, the queue is 0
The queue is empty, sleeping
The queue is 100000
The batch queue is 100000
__insert_data, the queue is 0
The queue is empty, sleeping
__insert_data, the queue is 0
The queue is empty, sleeping
Setting finish to true
__insert_data, the queue is 0
The queue is empty, sleeping
```

The first queue being empty makes sense (object initialization), but the next two seem like they should have items in them.  I'm also unclear as to why when the finish object is set to True, the worker makes it past the self._*finish check (I think it should print "*_finish flag has been set").

Comments welcome (as well as pointers to a library that might handle all of this by default).

Answer (score 0):

Data is never *implicitly* shared across processes.  Two consequences:

1. The `Manager.list()` created in the main program has nothing to do with the `Manager.list()` created in the worker process; and,
2. The `self.__finish` attribute in the main program has nothing to do with the `self.__finish` attribute in the worker process.

You should really back off and try much simpler code until this stuff makes better sense to you.  "The usual" way to do this stuff is along these lines (where I've thrown out all the class and method cruft so it's possible to see what's important here).  Note that there's no need for additional threads, or `sleep`ing, etc:

```
# shared data must be passed, even mp data structures
def worker(q):
    values_to_insert = []
    while True:
        item = q.get() # no need to sleep - blocks until data is ready
        if item is None:
            break
        values_to_insert.append(item)
        if len(values_to_insert) >= 39: # whatever - your `__batch_size`
            print "processing", values_to_insert
            values_to_insert = []
    # deal with any leftovers
    if values_to_insert:
        print "processing", values_to_insert

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing as mp
    import random

    q = mp.Queue(100)  # bounded queue
    proc = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(q,))
    proc.start()
    for item in random.sample(xrange(1, 1000000000), 100000):
        # will block if q has more than 100 items; blocking
        # waits for worker to catch up
        q.put(item)
    q.put(None)  # tell worker we're done
    proc.join()
```

Comment: Doesn't the `c = ConnectionWorker(conn, tbl)` start a new process and the `q = c.get_batch_insert_queue()` get a proxy for list to be used by the main running thread?

Comment: No offense intended, but your code is too convoluted for me to want to spend the time needed to untangle it in detail. Instead I gave you much simpler code that actually works ;-) You're not required to accept it. If you want to untangle it yourself, great! But then take my advice and whittle your code **way** down to just the essentials. You have so much horrid stuff going on here (like creating a `Manager()` as a side effect of compiling a class definition in the main program) that your code won't even run on, e.g., Windows.